# duplicate table show using `!table` in sqlline.sh

Tags: ignite, gridgain

`!table` command shows two duplicate tableName `DIMSTAT` when class eq. `DimStat.java`, code shows below:

```
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);
    Ignition.start(ConfigUtils.getIgniteCfg("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
    CacheConfiguration<String, DimStat> ccf = new CacheConfiguration<>();
    ccf.setSqlSchema("PUBLIC");
    ccf.setBackups(2);
    ccf.setName("DIMSTAT");
    ccf.setIndexedTypes(String.class, DimStat.class);  // DimStat
    ccf.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.DAYS, 1)));
    IgniteCache<String, Dim_Stat> cache = Ignition.ignite().getOrCreateCache(ccf);
```

[!table result using `DimStat.class`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tZB3.png)

**but it is ok when use `Dim_Stat.java`**

[!table result using `Dim_Stat.class`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBBli.png)

Comment: It looks like a bug in JDBC driver. `CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes()` causes JDBC driver to send table names twice. As a workaround, I would suggest using DDL commands https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/ddl I think the following example will be helpful as well https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryDdlExample.java

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I've filed a JIRA ticket in order to track this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7277

As a workaround, you can use DDL commands: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/ddl
Example is available here: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/CacheQueryDdlExample.java